# Can't understand the regression summary with dummy variables

Tags: r

So i just ran a linear model that is basically

```
regrex5 = lm(children ~ age + educ + electric + usemeth + educ*usemeth)
```

In which `eletric`and `usemeth` are dummy variables. When i asked for `summary(regrex5)`, this came to me:

```
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -1.153756   0.862801  -1.337  0.18122    
age            0.170755   0.002771  61.619  < 2e-16 ***
educ          -0.182312   0.038078  -4.788 1.74e-06 ***
electric0     -0.164087   0.823732  -0.199  0.84212    
electric1     -0.530384   0.825541  -0.642  0.52060    
usemeth0      -1.088850   0.241171  -4.515 6.50e-06 ***
usemeth1       0.022151   0.241337   0.092  0.92687    
educ:usemeth0  0.128012   0.038973   3.285  0.00103 ** 
educ:usemeth1  0.054131   0.038627   1.401  0.16116
```

I just can't understand why there are theses "usemeth0", "usemeth1", "electric0" and "electric1". Can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: If `eletric` and `usemeth` are stored as factors, try converting them to `as.numeric`

Comment: what is the output of `table(usemeth)` and `table(electric)`?

Comment: `> table(usemeth)
usemeth
   .    0    1 
  71 1812 2478 
> table(electric)
electric
   .    0    1 
   3 3747  611 ` is this helpful? if it isn't, please tell me another way to input this in stackoverflow @shuckle

Answer (score 1):

The reference levels of dummy variables are not included in the regression to avoid a perfect multicollinearity. Here, you have probably three levels for `usemeth` and `electric`(0, 1 and 2 which is the reference level).
Read [this](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/modules/coding-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-models/) and [this](http://www.algosome.com/articles/dummy-variable-trap-regression.html) to have a better understanding of dummy variables in regression.

Comment: yeah and i think i got what theses links are saying but i still can't really understand is the statistical meaning of the t value for each of the levels of usemeth and electric. how can i interpret them?

Comment: Coefficients are actually the mean of the reference group (usemeth2 and electric2). Theferore, in the summary `(intercept)`  is the mean of the reference group and for instance the coefficient of `electric0` (-0.164087), is the *mean of group 0 - group 2 (reference group)*  which is non significant here based on p-value (>0.5)

Answer (score 0):

these are the categories of your variable- look into your R levels for the eletric for example by calling the `str(data$electric)` and you can see the number of levels and which is assigned to what level. let's say your electric has two levels of "practical" and " theory"- In R practical is given level 0 and theory is level 1 and those are what you see in your model as `electric0`  and `electric1`.
electric 0 means when your "practical" electiric=1 then that's the t value, and similarly electric 1 means when your "theroy"=1 then that's the t-value.

Comment: thanks! but then can you help me understand theses values a little better? I wanted to test if `electric` as a whole is relevant to the model, how can i do it? i would know how to do it if i had a single t value to the `electric` variable i guess...

Comment: That is in your summary, you have usemeth0 being significant- that is among all usemeth categories, only usemeth0 significantly influences your response variable. or for the observations which have a usemeth0 in their use meth field will have a different response compared to the the rest with no usemeth0, everything else held consistent.